# .map is not a function React.js

Tags: arrays, reactjs, array.prototype.map

here is my data fetch

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const jwt = sessionStorage.getItem('Token')
    const user = jwtDecode(jwt)
    const token = sessionStorage.getItem('Token')
    console.log(token)
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/animals/animal/client?clientId=" + user.id, {
        method: "get",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": `${token}`,
        },
    })
    const data = await response.json();

    console.log(data);
    this.setState({
        animal: data[0], loading: false,

    });
    this.setState({
        medicamento1: this.state.animal.medicamentos[0],
        medicamento2: this.state.animal.medicamentos[1],
        medicamentos: this.state.animal.medicamentos,
       
    });
    console.log(this.state.animal.medicamentos)


}
```

my modal map

```
     <Modal>
  <Modal.Body>
    {medicamentos.map((medicamento) => (
      <MedicamentosMap />
    ))}
    
  </Modal.Body>
  <Modal.Footer>
    <Button
      type="submit"
      value="Submit"
      className="btn btn-primary"
      variant="primary"
      onClick={() => {
        this.handleClose();
      }}
    >
      Fechar
    </Button>
  </Modal.Footer>
</Modal>
```

and here is my map function

```
    const MedicamentosMap = () => {
    return (
        <div className='medicamentosModal'>
            <a>Medicamentos</a>
            <a>descricao</a>


            <div className='linhaHorizontal'></div>
            <p style={{ marginLeft: '75px' }}>teste</p>
            <p style={{
                marginLeft: '254px',
                marginTop: '-40px'
            }}>aiai</p>
            <div className='linhaVertical'></div>


        </div>

    )}
    
   export default MedicamentosMap;
```

so when i try to map my data on the modal is appears .map is not a function and i dont know why because .map is suposed to list an array but it seems something is wrong , i cheked my console.log and my data returns a list of arrays so that was suposed to work, anyone can help me?

[image: data]

Comment: Without knowing what the data is you are working with, I can only guess that `medicamentos` is *not* an array the first time the component renders. The error is pretty clear, at some point the value is not an array. Since we don't have a runnable or complete example there is not much we can say except to make sure that either the value is always an array or to check whether it's an array before mapping over it.

Comment: i edited the post and added an image that is what i get from medicamentos

Comment: i also declared medicamentos as an array with state

Comment: Which line produces this log output?

Comment: try this medicamentos?.map((medicamento)